# Eclipse CDT: Target name variable for exernal build tool

Tags: eclipse, cmake, eclipse-cdt

I'm use Eclipse with CMake as external build tool. I have a Release and Debug build configuration and a number of build targets ("target_1", "target_2", "all").

I'm trying to pass the name of the build target to the "make" command that uses the Makefile generated by CMake. E.g., I want it to call "make target_1" when building "target_1". I assumed there would be a variable in Eclipse with the target name but I can't seem to find it.

How do I pass the target name to an external build command? Is there a variable with the target name?